# @RequestMapping HTTP test not available

Tags: java, rest, http, intellij-idea

I am new to java and I am following a tutorial but I faced a problem. When I want to test a POST, I don't find ENDPOINTS tool window and when I write @RequestMapping it shows up like this:
[image]

but in the tutorial, it shows it like this:
[image]
so the globe sign which helps in making HTTP client test is not available.

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can help me with this.
I am using INTELLIJ 2021.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

The `Endpoints` tool is a plugin compatible with the `Ultimate` version of intelliJ.

So if you want to use that tool you'll have to upgrade from community edition to the Ultimate edition.

Comment: Ops! I didn't know that. Is there any other way that I can have an HTTP test in the community version?

Comment: There's no alternative plugin to do that. But you can use other well known tools like Postman to perform HTTP request :)